# Script that replaces all "*.html" file names with "*.html.<username>"

Tags: shell, unix

Write a script that replaces all `*.html` file names with `*.html.<username>` in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find`'s `-exec` option:

```
$ find . -name "*.html" -exec mv '{}' '{}'.${USER} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `perl-rename` installed (called `rename` on Debian-based and many other systems, `/usr/bin/site_perl/rename` on others), you can run:

```
rename "s/\.html$/.html.$USER/" *
```

If you don't have the perl rename, but have the compiled one, you can do:

```
rename '.html' ".html.$USER" *
```

If you have neither, use the shell:

```
for f in *.html; do mv "$f" "$f"."$USER"; done
```